# Convert from json Object String to Java Object om.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException

Tags: java, json, converters

I have a question regarding parsing string to java object.
I have this response:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "paginated": false,
    "data": [{
        "user": {
            "id": 21,
            "email": "kjhk@gmail.com",
            "access_token": "ai_wy-tTLLEyRCPAF86dWPJdQ77gefsTPwBkvtlEkNs",
            "test": []
        }
    }],
    "message": ""
}
```

And I want to get the status

I created this class and set only the status since this is the only field I want and all the rest of the response not important

```
package responseObjects;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LogInResponse {



    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @JsonProperty("status")
    public String status;


    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

In the program I send request and get the response, however when I try to set it as java object it failed
int this line`LogInResponse res = gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(),LogInResponse.class);`

```
public class TestMain {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    JsonObject bodyJson = new JsonObject();
    JsonObject responseJson = new JsonObject();

    MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

  public String httpPost(String url, String json) throws IOException {
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), json);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        String  strResponse = response.body().string();
      JsonObject jsonObjectResponse = new JsonParser().parse(strResponse).getAsJsonObject();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    LogInResponse res = gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(),LogInResponse.class);
        return response.body().string();
    }
```

this is the exception

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813)
```

Can someone advise what is wrong? how can I get the status from the response? 
regards

Comment: print out `strResponse` and share the output

Comment: What is the output of `System.out.println(response.body().toString())`?

Comment: Also, note that you're using Jackson annotations, but you're using Gson. So the annotations won't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From OkHttp's documentation about [`body()`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-response/body)

> Returns a non-null value if this response was passed to Callback.onResponse or returned from Call.execute. **Response bodies must be closed and may be consumed only once.**

That is, you're using it <s>twice</s> three times (including your return statement). You already have it inside of `strResponse`. Keep using that one. And `close()` it, while you're at it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you use `response.body().string()` to get a JSON string, but in failing line you write `response.body().toString()` which is a different method.